# How to Update a Table from Avg value of a Query

Tags: vba, database, string, ms-access, average

I am using this query to update Products table from MovingAvg query which is getting the Avg() of Product Price from purchase table  but its gives error that its not an update able query

```
UPDATE Products 
INNER JOIN MovingAvg ON Products.ID = MovingAvg.[Product ID] 
SET Products.[Standard Cost] = MovingAvg.[Moving Avg]
WHERE (((Products.ID)=MovingAvg.[Product ID]));
```

Comment: What's wrong with your `update` command? What's exact error message?

Comment: "Operation must use an updateable query"  is the exact error

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing it to:

```sql
UPDATE Products 
INNER JOIN MovingAvg ON Products.ID = MovingAvg.[Product ID] 
SET Products.[Standard Cost] = MovingAvg.[Moving Avg]
```